# Convert monthly data to yearly data in Pandas Time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe that has closing prices of Stock at the end of every month. How do I aggregate the data so that I get the closing price of every year.

Sample Data:

[image]

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("historical_data.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.resample('A')
print(df.head())
```

I read somewhere that "A" is the parameter used for Yearly aggregation,
but I just get the same output without the yearly aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign the result of your resample.  Also, use `.last()` to get the last price for each year.

```
df = df.resample('A').last()
```

Comment: thanks, it solved it. I assigned the result to a new dataframe with .last() and it worked.